# Localhost is not allowed access when using AJAX to request JSON from API

Tags: javascript, json

EDIT:Here is the error message: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/xxxxxxxxxxxxapicodexxxxxxxxxxxxx/london. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Then this is the code which I am using to try and display the latitude value from the JSON:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/d4abb1b19adb13e42eac5a7beac6f4dbeb4b4ba4/" + searchBox.value, function(data) {
    alert("test");
    alert(data.geocodingResults.COORDINATES.latitude);   
});
```

Comment: It is `geocoding_results` not `geocodingResults`

Comment: What does it say if you look at your JavaScript error console?

Comment: @Quentin There are errors but the page reloads too quickly and I cannot see them.

Comment: Change your preferences to preserve the console when a new page is loaded then.

Comment: Here is the error message: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/xxxxxxxxxxxxapicodexxxxxxxxxxxxx/london. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, should be `geocoding_results` instead of `geocodingResults`:

```
alert(data.geocoding_results.COORDINATES.latitude);
```